# DCount using Multiple Criteria

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am not sure why my code does not return the right number of records.
I have:

```
counter = DCount("*", "tbl1", "[Check] = FALSE OR DateDiff('d', [CheckDate], 
Date()) > 365 And [Room] = '" & Forms!frmSelect.txbSelect.Value & "'")
checkIndicator.Caption = "(" & counter & ")" & " available!"
```

It seems that the part with `[Check] = FALSE OR DateDiff('d', [CheckDate], Date()) > 365` works fine but the the entire code is not. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to provide more information. For example some data points, the result the formula gives and the result you expect.

Comment: Could be you need parenthesis around the OR clause. Parenthesis are critical when mixing AND and OR operators - think Algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code will return a count of records in `tbl1` for which:

- `[Check] = FALSE` (for ***any*** value of `[Room]`)

**OR**

- `DateDiff('d', [CheckDate], Date()) > 365` **AND** `[Room] = Forms!frmSelect.txbSelect.Value`

---

Depending on the desired result, I'm guessing that you require `[Room] = Forms!frmSelect.txbSelect.Value` to ***always*** be true, and so the logic should be enclosed with parentheses in the following way:

```
"([Check] = FALSE OR DateDiff('d', [CheckDate], Date()) > 365) And [Room] = '" & Forms!frmSelect.txbSelect.Value & "'"
 ^                                                           ^
 |                                                           |
 +----------------- Added parentheses here ------------------+
```

This is now returning the count of records in `tbl1` for which:

- `[Room] = Forms!frmSelect.txbSelect.Value`

**AND**

- `[Check] = FALSE` **OR** `DateDiff('d', [CheckDate], Date()) > 365`